# method of receiving data from firebase is not working

Tags: java, android

I am using the SwipeCard library and the shapeableimageview is stored in a separate xml file that is connected to the main layout activity xml.  there is also an adapter for this SwipeCard.  data is not received although there are no errors in the code

activity with receive method

```
private void getUsermenwomInfo()
{
    DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Userwoman_men");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()&&snapshot.getChildrenCount()>0)
            {
                String name=snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                nameusercard.setText(name);
                if (snapshot.hasChild("image")) {
                    String image = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.get().load(image).into(imageosnovnoe);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

xml with shapeableimageview

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageosnovnoe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                 />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearhori"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/like"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/sas"



                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/disslike"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/aan"

                    />


            </LinearLayout>




    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

her adapter java class

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Integer> list;


    public SwipeAdapter(Context context,List<Integer>list) {
        this.context=context;
        this.list=list;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View view;
     if(convertView==null)
     {
         view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_koloda,parent,false);

     }else {
         view=convertView;
     }
     return view;
    }
   
}
```

how to change my code or write a new one so that image and textview data is taken from firebase and inserted into shapeableimageview and textview from this separate xml?  and is it correct that I wrote the method inside the main activity and not in the adapter?  Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried logging `onCancelled` error message?

Comment: no, how is it done?  just in toast + message? I'm just starting out, so I don't really understand)